# in R regex use optional charater behind a capture group

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract a string from a longer string. The capture group may be followed by an underscore or by nothing. Here's an example:

```
id <- "begin_station1"
id <- "begin_station2_end"
sub(".*station(.+)_?.*", "\\1", id)
```

unfortunately the `?` does not seem to work like this. For using the
first id returnes "1" but using the second id returns "2_end".

EDIT: what I want to extract can be any number of digits or letters. Station codes vary a lot.

Comment: What substring/group are you trying to extract? The numeric value after "station" ?

Comment: If you are trying to capture a number, try `sub("^.*station(\\d+).*$", "\\1", id)`

Comment: If it can be any value (not just a number), try `sub("^.*station([^_]+).*$", "\\1", id)`

Comment: `sub("^.*(\\d+).*$", "\\1", id) [1] "1"`, also.

Comment: @AllanCameron 's answer seems to work. Thank's a lot! (I had tried ```^_``` before but apparently in a wrong way.

Comment: I'd still like to know why the ```?``` does not work.